# CSS Before and After Elements Cant't See on IOS Devices

Tags: css

the + and - symbols that I created with CSS do not appear on IOS Devices. I also added it as a webkit. You can see sample CSS below.

```
accordion .accordion__title:before,
.accordion .accordion__title:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: transform .4s;
  -moz-transition: transform .4s;
  -ms-transition: transform .4s;
  -o-transition: transform .4s;
  transition: transform .4s;
}
```

Comment: It should be `::before` and `::after`, respectly.

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet within your question and check it definitely shows the problem on IOS devices. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example